# Что делать, когда Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Tags: git, git-push

Делаю `git push`, получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке.

```
To git@github.com:name/project.git
   21b430d..dd378ca  master -> master
 ! [rejected]        release -> release (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jkubicek/my_proj.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration
hint: variable to 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

как я понял, кроме

```
git push https://name@site.ru/visit/visit.0.11.git
```

туда еще указать свою ветку, как ее указывать надо?

Comment: пушить и коммитить - это немого разные вещи.

При пуше нужно указывать имя удаленной ветки в виде `origin/имя_ветки`.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, за ответ, но куда писать origin/имя_ветки.?

Comment: @KoVadim git push https://name@site.ru/visit/visit.0.11.git origin/имя_ветки. так? или...

Comment: так не пошел

Comment: Вначале выполните `git status`. Там будет такое

    Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

origin - это псевдоним удаленного сервера, master - это ветка на удаленном сервере. Ваша локальная ветка обычно совпадает по названию.

Потом делаем

    git push origin имя_ветки

В некоторых случаях origin может называться по другому.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за вам помощь!!! ++Вам (получилось)

Comment: Я всегда на всякий случай полностью имя веток пишу:
    
    git push origin master:master

Comment: Применил к ответу немного угадывательной магии относительно обрезанной части сообщения.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы уже наверняка, сделайте текущую ветку дефолтной (чтобы не промахнуться при пуше):

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Потом верните обратно в мастер. И не забывайте забирать изменения из веток через `git fetch`

Comment: делать дефолтной ветку для пуша... это печальное дело.

`git push -f` - это лучше не рассказывать. Так как этой командой можно сделать сильно много плохого.

Comment: Ветку дефолтной делать предлагаю на время я. Человеку решение проблемы сулит метод мой.
Про -f  тоже указал, что хардкорный он. Код видите, а русские буквы игнорируете? )

Comment: @KoVadim В `push.default=current` ничего плохого нет, при этом можно делать `git push <remote>` не заботясь о том, какая ветка текущая, и без страха запушить какие-то соседние локальные ветки, которые пушить не хотелось. Лучше, чем `matching`, и лишь немногим страшнее, чем `simple`.

А вот `git push -f` это саботаж, а не совет.

Comment: @pirj: удалил про `push -f`.